# Terminal Startup Scripts?

Tags: bash, terminal

I recently downloaded Ruby onto my mac via rbenv, and I read instructions that showed me how to start up rbenv every time I open terminal. Is there a way to view all the startup scripts for terminal?

Here's the script I used:

> echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: "all the startup scripts for terminal" – Most likely you mean startup scripts for the shell you use. The terminal (terminal emulator) you use and its "startup scripts" (if any) are probably irrelevant here. Please see [*What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618)

Answer (score 0):

Most startup settings for terminal/console (including scripts) are kept in or loaded from `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, which are hidden files in your user home directory.

You can edit them manually with a text editor to suit your preferences (make a backup of them first, just in case).

Answer (score 0):

What profiles (Shell init scripts) are parsed on process spawn depends on your shell. This is the documentation [*man page* for `bash`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/bash/bash.1.en.html#INVOCATION). There are two different sets of scrips `source`ed depending on if the shell is spawned with `--login` or without.

### `bash --login`

> it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order

### `bash`

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc

### note

The only impact the very weird `--login` flag has, is the init script file location. If you configure your system, just do `~/.profile` and make `~/.bashrc`  symlink to it.